# AngularJS Karma Jasmine : Expected undefined to be defined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to AngularJS and working on adding unit tests in Karma and Jasmine. I have a following controller code whose method I am trying to test. I am getting the error saying that  Expected undefined to be defined. I am not sure why SpyOn is not able to recognize the method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

newclaim.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'createnewclaim';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$location', '$routeParams', 'sessionKeys', 'securelogins',
        'localStorageService', 'common', 'config', 'datacontext', createnewclaim]);

    function createnewclaim($location, $routeParams, sessionKeys, securelogins, localStorageService, common, config, datacontext) {


//some code here
```

My test file code

```
describe('testing AngularJS Test Suite', function () {

        beforeEach(module('app'));

        describe('Testing AngularJS NewClaim Controller', function () {
            var scope = {};
            var ctrl;
            var controllerId = 'createnewclaim';

            beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, localStorageService, common, datacontext, sessionKeys, securelogins) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
          
                ctrl = function () {
                    $controller(controllerId, {
                        $scope: scope,
                        localStorageService: localStorageService,
                        common: common,
                        datacontext: datacontext,
                        sessionKeys: sessionKeys,
                        securelogins: securelogins
                    });
                };
            }));

            it('controller defined', inject(function () {
                expect(ctrl).toBeTruthy();
            }));

            it('controller function defined', inject( function () {
                ctrl();
                expect(ctrl.createnewclaim).toBeDefined();
            }));
            
        });
    });

})();
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the ctrl function, hence, undefined.

Comment: @Esaith could you pls tell me what should I be returning in controller function in order to get the ctrl object working?

Comment: return $controller(controllerId, { ....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Ignore the return. You need to be using the scope as your test, not the ctrl.

```
describe('testing AngularJS Test Suite', function () {

        beforeEach(module('app'));

        describe('Testing AngularJS NewClaim Controller', function () {
            var scope = {};
            var ctrl;
            var controllerId = 'createnewclaim';

            beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, localStorageService, common, datacontext, sessionKeys, securelogins) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
          
                ctrl = function () {
                    return $controller(controllerId, {
                        $scope: scope,
                        localStorageService: localStorageService,
                        common: common,
                        datacontext: datacontext,
                        sessionKeys: sessionKeys,
                        securelogins: securelogins
                    });
                };
            }));

            it('controller defined', inject(function () {
                ctrl();
                expect(scope).toBeTruthy();
            }));

            it('controller function defined', inject( function () {
                ctrl();
                expect(scope.createnewclaim).toBeDefined();
            }));            
        });
    });
})();
```